# Get file from Remote server and append data in local server file

Tags: perl, ssh, sftp

I have a script which gets file from remote machine to local machine and appends data to the existing file if the file is already present in the local machine.

Code below: This uses `Net::SFTP::Foreign` Perl module.

```
.
.
my $remote_dir = "/REMOTE/MACHINE/PATH";
my $file        = "Report9_202007.txt";

my $local_dir   = "/LOCAL/MACHINE/PATH";

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(host=>$host , user=>$user , password=>$pass);
$sftp->die_on_error("Unable to establish SFTP connection");

$sftp->put("$remote_dir/$file","$local_dir/$file", append=>1, overwrite=>0) or die "put failed:".$sftp->error;
$sftp->disconnect;
.
.
```

Above script works perfectly fine. As you can see I am appending data of the report to the existing file and not overwriting into it in local machine in condition `..append=>1, overwrite=>0)`

Similarly, I have some dependency on Perl module on one of the VM so I thought of doing same operation using `Net::OpenSSH` perl module.

Script below:

```
.
.
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host,
                            user => $user,
                            password => $passwd
);
$ssh->error and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;
.
.
$ssh->scp_put({glob => 1}, "$remote_dir/$file", "$local_dir/$file")
        or die "scp failed: " . $ssh->error;
.
```

But here its overwriting the existing file when it puts the file from remote server to local server. How can I modify the script which should do a same operation like `Net::SFTP::Foreign` does while putting the file by setting `overwrite` value as `0` and `append` as `1` in `scp_put`?

Comment: A workaround could be to write to a temp file, and then append that to the file

Comment: you can use `Net::SFTP::Foreign` from `Net::OpenSSH`: `$ssh->sftp->put("$remote_dir/$file","$local_dir/$file", append=>1, overwrite=>0)`

Comment: @salva without `Net::SFTP::Foreign` is it possible to achieve it by the use of `Net::OpenSSH`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick as long as the remote system runs some kind of UNIX:

```perl
open my $fh, '>>', $local_file or die $!
$ssh->system({stdout_fh => $fh}, cat => $remote_file) or die $ssh->error
```